# makefile compiling multiples targets

Tags: c, makefile

This is my first post in this forum. Sorry for bothering but I've been looking for something similar and strangely I couldn't find it. Here's the issue.
I have three (main) files with no headers and I want to compile them either at once (if I simply type "make") or one by one (if I specify the name of the file with no extension). So I built my makefile but something is wrong in the command

```
$(TARGETS): $(BUILDS_DIR)% : $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
```

where I got this error

make: *** No rule to make target....

here's the complete file

```
.SUFFIXES: .c
ROOT = $(addprefix $(PWD), /)
BUILDS_DIR = $(addprefix $(ROOT), builds/)
SRCS_DIR   = $(addprefix $(ROOT), src/)

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCS_DIR)*.c)

TARGETS = ${SRCS:$(SRCS_DIR)%.c=%}
EXES = ${addprefix $(BUILDS_DIR), $(TARGETS)}

CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -O3

RM = rm -f

.PHONY: all $(TARGETS) clean

all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): $(BUILDS_DIR)% : $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) \
        $< \
        -o $@
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Compile successfully! ***\n" ;

clean:
    $(RM)   $(EXES) \
        $(SRCS_DIR)*~
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Cleanup complete! ***\n"
```

Where am I wrong? I guess the answer is very silly and probably based on a basic error.

thanks in advance

Comment: `No rule to make target`... what? What's the full error?

Comment: Run `make -d ...`, this will show you what `make` is doing.

Comment: Which or who's `make` are you using? It is [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) as found on most/all GNU/Linux systems, or `make` from one of the [BSD projects](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/tools-make.html), or a third-party port? GNU make is sometime called `gmake` NetBSD make is sometime referred to, or available as a package, known as [bmake](http://www.crufty.net/help/sjg/bmake.htm). Note, cmake is a different build system. I _believe_ `addprefix` and `wildcard` are GNU Make specific, while `.SUFFIXES` is fairly old style and should be unnecessary.

Comment: the .SUFFIXES line always needs to be a list, with all the suffixes that will be used.  In general, it is best to NOT put a .SUFFIXES statement in a make file, except in very special circumstances.  Then the default list will be used.

Comment: I see no references to include files nor libraries in your make file.  This leaves me to wonder what the files could possibly do when they have no I/O, no math, nothing.

Comment: Indeed, I'm using GNU Make and the files just convert some data format to another one. that's why I don't need the -lm. About the .SUFFIXES statement, I actually copied and pasted from a someone else's makefile maybe not so recent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming GNU Make (since you use its syntax).

The, or the first, problem is that you are trying to rewrite the target [static **pattern**](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Usage.html#Static-Usage) incorrectly, by trying to concatenate the target directory to the *pattern*, rather than simply using the target's filename.

You had:

```
$(TARGETS): $(BUILDS_DIR)% : $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The solution is to use add the directory path on the command line

```
$(TARGETS): % : $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(BUILDS_DIR)$@
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! actually with this correction it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that your three source files are `file1.c`, `file2.c` and `file3.c`.  I would created the makefile to look like this (assuming GNU make)

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -pedantic

RM = rm -f

OBJS = file1.o file2.o file3.o

PROG=my_program

$(PROG) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)

all : clean $(PROG)

file1 : file1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c file1.c -o file1.o

file2 : file2.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c file2.c -o file2.o

file3 : file3.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c file3.c -o file3.o

clean :
    $(RM) *.o $(PROG) *.*~
```

A sample using this make file is (I use the -n to show what rules would be run, but not actually run them because my source files are empty files for testing.)

```
    [******@broadsword junk]$ make -n
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic   -c -o file1.o file1.c
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic   -c -o file2.o file2.c
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic   -c -o file3.o file3.c
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic file1.o file2.o file3.o -o my_program
    [******@broadsword junk]$ make -n file1
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic -c file1.c -o file1.o
```

We can shorten the above make file my making use of wild-cards;

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -ansi -Wall -pedantic

RM = rm -f

OBJS = file1.o file2.o file3.o

PROG=my_program

$(PROG) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)

all : clean $(PROG)

% : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@.o

clean :
    $(RM) *.o $(PROG) *.*~

We need to append a '.o' to the output file name so that we are creating files in the format defined by the `$(OBJ)` variable of the first build rule works correctly.  Doing this gives the following example runs:

```
    [******@broadsword junk]$ make -n
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic   -c -o file1.o file1.c
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic   -c -o file2.o file2.c
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic   -c -o file3.o file3.c
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic file1.o file2.o file3.o -o my_program
    [******@broadsword junk]$ make -n file2
    gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic -c file2.c -o file2.o
```

BTW, I personally don't mind typing an extra two characters and I like having my target match the output of the set of rules that get run, so I would write the rules as either

```
     file1.o : file1.c
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c file1.c -o file1.o
```

or

```
     %.o :%.c
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Finally I strongly suspect that when we execute `make` or `make all`, we are not running the file-specific rules in the lower part of the makefile, rather we are running the the built in rule described in the GNU manual as: "n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form `$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c`".

Comment: Thanks this also works but my idea was to skip the object files, as I didn't need to link anything later. but it might be more clear and simple to apply the classical approach. Thanks a lot!

Comment: **No** Your example Makefile is not recommended. Besides being needlessly complex, it is _less_ powerful than the standard built in [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html). Finally it is _not_ normal to have `all` depend on the `clear` target. It defeats the purpose of `make` to only re-compile what has changed.

Comment: @mctylr, in what you put in pastebin, why have the all target at all?  You have `all : $(PROG)` with no rules and then the next target line is `$(PROG) : $(OBJS)` with a rule to build the program.  So executing make as `make`, we get trigger the all target which in turn triggers the `$(PROG)` target.  Seems simpler just to delete the "all" target and leave the "$(PROG)" target as the first target in the makefile.  Additionally, to me, the command `make all` implies recompiling everything, not just what has recently changed, thus the dependency on clean.

Comment: The `all` target is merely convenience / convention. For a small project with only one executable it is not necessary. You can use multiple targets in a GNU Make command line e.g. `make clean all` to cleanly rebuild everything. Or create an `cleanbuild` or `rebuild` target to do the same thing. `cleanbuild: clean all`.